# In column A I have Purchase Orders and in column B I have prices. How Can I identify when a repeated Purchase order has at least one price under 500?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In column A I have Purchase Orders and in column B I have prices.
How Can I identify when a repeated Purchase Order has at least one price under 500?

Here is an example:

[image]

I was trying to identify the purchase orders that had at least one price under 500

Comment: There are many ways. To display as you show, I suggest using Conditional Formatting. Please edit your question to include what you have tried, and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=LET(f,FILTER($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2),
AND(MIN(f)<500,ROWS(f)>1))
```

It filters the data - and then checks for the minimum value and the number of returned rows.

If returned rows > 1 --> repeated orders

If min value < 500 --> second condition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple <kbd>COUNTIFS()</kbd> function is what you need:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,"<500")
```

---

For conditional formatting:

[image]

---

• Highlight the range of cells `A2:C13`

• Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

• From `New Formatting Rule` select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and enter the above formula

• Click on format for specific formatting preference

• Click Ok Twice. Done.

---